# Meaning of "the helicopter comes in to land"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> The helicopter comes in to land.

What does this sentence mean?

Does it mean that the helicopter comes in and lands or does it mean it comes in with the intention of landing?

Comment: *The helicopter comes in* = ***arrives*** (at the general location of the speaker). Where ***to land*** is effectively an "adverb of purpose" - the "reason" the helicopter arrived (or the "result, outcome" of it arriving) was so it could land (on the helipad or whatever).

Comment: Comes into the land= approaches the place where it will land

Comment: @Lambie "Comes into the land" sounds like a poetic way to say it crashes

Answer (score 6):

It means that the helicopter comes in with the intention to land, e.g.,

> "As **the helicopter comes in to land**, the rotor blades force air downward.
> This downward force of air hits the ground when the helicopter lands
> and shoots back up."
>
> -*[How It Goes](https://books.google.com/books?id=eILBJLNUs4kC&q=%22helicopter%20comes%20in%20to%20land%22&dq=%22helicopter%20comes%20in%20to%20land%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&printsec=frontcover&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjdzKvFgd7wAhXDWM0KHcWIAXAQ6AEwAXoECAgQAg)* (1994) by Kate Scarbarough, pg. 20

However, it is not uncommon for it to imply that the helicopter actually lands, e.g.,

> "...**the helicopter comes in to land** near to a flare marker a few
> 100 feet away, three men get out and are directed to a large group of
> people already stood trying to look into the darkness."
>
> -*[Demonstrative](https://www.google.com/books/edition/DEMONSTRATIVE_Pocket_Book/dHlXAgAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22helicopter%20comes%20in%20to%20land%22&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover)* (2011) by Kevin Lomas, pg. 72

Theoretically, one could maybe interpret "to land" not as the infinitive form of the verb "land" but as a prepositional phrase in which "land" is a nouncount noun and the object of the preposition "to," in which case it would mean that the helicopter reaches land, except if so, the preposition wouldn't be "to" but something else, like "onto" since helicopters *arrive* or *set down* "on" the ground or "onto" the ground, not "to" the ground. That would be an awkward construction, though. The phrasal verb "comes in" would likely get replaced, like with "arrives" or some other verb. Maybe if the vehicle were a [hovercraft](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hovercraft) instead of a helicopter, such ambiguity of "comes in to land" could be interpreted.